# Bitmap out of bounds

Tags: android, for-loop, bitmap, error-handling, crop

i'm trying to create a function that croppes images in 3x3/4x4/5x5 depending on the difficulty a player chooses, and puts them in a bitmap array. But when i run this function i get the error:

x + width  must be <= bitmap.width()!

I tried to see what i was doing wrong but i can't see it. Here is the code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Bundle extras = this.getIntent().getExtras();
    resource = extras.getInt("Image");
    difficulty = extras.getInt("difficulty");
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), resource);
    divideImages(bmp);
```

and

```
private void divideImages(Bitmap bmp) {

    int width = bmp.getWidth();
    int height =bmp.getHeight();
    float w_ratio = (float) width/bmp.getWidth();
    int scaledwidth = (int) (bmp.getWidth()*w_ratio);
    int scaledheight = (int) (bmp.getHeight()*w_ratio);
    Bitmap scaledbmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp,scaledwidth,scaledheight,true);

    switch(difficulty){
        case 0:
            for(int i=0;i<3;i++){

                System.out.println("row no. "+i);

                for(int j=0;j<3;j++){

                    System.out.println("Column no."+j);
                    int startx = (scaledwidth/3)*j;
                    int starty = (scaledheight/3)*i;
                    Bitmap b1  = Bitmap.createBitmap(scaledbmp,startx,starty,scaledwidth,scaledheight);
                    bs.add(b1);
                    b1 = null;
                    }
                bmp = null;
            }
            break;                                
        case 1:
            for(int i=0;i<4;i++){

                System.out.println("row no. "+i);

                for(int j=0;j<4;j++){

                    System.out.println("Column no."+j);
                    int startx = (scaledwidth/4)*j;
                    int starty = (scaledheight/4)*i;
                    Bitmap b1  = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp,startx,starty,scaledwidth,scaledheight);
                    bs.add(b1);
                    b1 = null;
                    }
                bmp = null;
            }
        case 2:
            for(int i=0;i<5;i++){

                System.out.println("row no. "+i);

                for(int j=0;j<5;j++){

                    System.out.println("Column no."+j);
                    int startx = (scaledwidth/5)*j;
                    int starty = (scaledheight/5)*i;
                    Bitmap b1  = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp,startx,starty,scaledwidth,scaledheight);
                    bs.add(b1);
                    b1 = null;
                    }
                bmp = null;
            }
    }
}
```

I suppose Bitmap b1 is out of boundary but i don't seem to see why.....

Comment: Your problem maybe comes from rounding when you create scaled size or startx/starty, did you try with `int startx = (scaledwidth*j)/3;` ?

Comment: Something looks strange, as `width = bmp.getWidth()` w_ratio is always equal to 1 and so scaledbmp is same as bmp, am I missing something ?

Comment: if i do that i get exactly the same error

Comment: yeah i should make a variable that makes screensize and of width and height

Comment: One last more comment, when you create b1 (ie in easy mode) I think it should be scaledWidth/3 (scaledHeight/3) instead of scaledWidth (scaledHeight)

Comment: what do you meen by that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66065/discussion-between-gaetan-maisse-and-kees-til).